# Get total number of parents

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am upgrading a legacy application and I need to find the number of parents certain rows in a table have.

I was thinking of using a  declared procedure for this, but i'm having trouble figuring it out how to make it work.

Basically you have a table with id and parent

```
= id = parent =
= 0  = 0 =
= 1  = 0 =
= 2  = 1 =
= 3  = 1 =
= 4  = 2 =
```

ID is unique, and parent is variable depending on what was used to create that entry, but it will always match a row with matching ID

What i'd like to achieve is calling one procedure that returns all matching parent numbers as a simple iterable result set.

So if i were to do getAllParents(4) it should return me 2, 1, 0

My failed attempts at looping have brought me so far

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getNumberOfParents @start int  @current int 
as
begin
SELECT parent FROM test where id=@start
if(parent > 0)
   begin
      set @current = @current + 1;
      set @current = @current + getNumberOfParents(parent,@current);
   end
end
```

Due to restrictions I cannot use an extra table to achieve this, otherwise i'd be easy heh. i can however make temptables that can be cleaned up after the method exits.

Comment: Why don't You use while loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without a while loop by the use of a recursive `CTE`:

```
DECLARE @lookupId INT = 4

;WITH ParentsCTE AS (
   SELECT id, parent
   FROM #mytable
   WHERE id = @lookupId

   UNION ALL

   SELECT m.id, m.parent
   FROM #mytable AS m
   INNER JOIN ParentsCTE AS p ON m.id = p.parent
   WHERE m.id <> m.parent
)
SELECT parent
FROM ParentsCTE
```

The anchor member of the above `CTE`:

```
SELECT id, parent
FROM #mytable
WHERE id = @lookupId
```

returns the *immediate parent* of the 'lookup id'.

The recursive member:

```
SELECT m.id, m.parent
FROM #mytable AS m
INNER JOIN ParentsCTE AS p ON m.id = p.parent
WHERE m.id <> m.parent
```

keeps adding parents up the hierarchy until a *root node* (`m.id <> m.parent` predicate detects this) has been reached.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6cd8b/1)

Comment: Okay. I see that it works. The logic behind it evades me though. Could you explain how it works that ParentsCTE can be accessed from within itself? I understand that a CTE can reference itself, but what I don't understand is against which values it tests itself. Basically what I want to know is what are the logic steps.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets There is a very good explanation about how recursive CTEs work here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: lol, i just read that. See my updated followup question. Could you explain the logic steps/tests? It doesn't really explain that.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Check especially this point: `The semantics of the recursive execution is as follows:`. In my post above I tried to explain how step 1 through 5 work in this case.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets The anchor member produces T0, i.e. record `{4,2}`. Try to run the recursive member one at a time, first time with T0 as input, then T1, etc.

Comment: So in essence, the top select runs, then the bottom(anchor?) select which executes the top select on success which passes to the bottom... I

Comment: @MichaelDibbets The top select *is the anchor* and runs *only once* producing T0. The second select, i.e. the recursive part, runs until it produces an empty result set. The recursive part has initially T0 as input and produces T1, In the second iteration T1 is the input, etc.

Comment: Ah. Okay. Now its making sense.

Answer (score 2):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (id INT, parent INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
 (0 ,  0), 
 (1 ,  0), 
 (2 ,  1),
 (3 ,  1), 
 (4 ,  2)
```

### Query

```
 -- Id you want all the parents for 
 DECLARE @ParentsFor INT = 4

;with parents as 
(
  select ID, parent
  from @Table
  where parent IS NOT NULL
  union all 
  select p.ID, t.parent
  from parents p
    inner join @Table t on p.parent = t.ID
      and t.ID <> t.parent
)
select Distinct
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + Cast(parent AS VarChar(10))
             FROM parents
             WHERE ID = @ParentsFor
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
FROM parents
```

### Result

```
2,1,0
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/3348)

Answer (score 0):

**[Fiddle Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/889b3/2)**

try:

```
declare @id varchar(max)=''
declare @getid int=4
while @getid>0

begin
select @id=@id+cast(parent as varchar(10))+',' from tab_1
where id=@getid
select @getid=parent from tab_1 where id=@getid
end

select @id
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use while loop as presented in this example:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/24/sql-server-simple-example-of-while-loop-with-continue-and-break-keywords/